# Python - как не останавливать выполнение скрипта при ошибке?

Tags: python, postgresql, исключения, try

На первой части скрипта при неуникальных данных в вставляемых элементах возникает ошибка останавливающая скрипт.
Как сделать чтобы возникающая ошибка не останавливала выполнение скрипта, и скрипт выполнял дальнейшую работу?
В моем понимании в случае ошибки 1го"try:", должен обрабатываться 2й"try:" но этого не происходит....

Ошибка:
cur.execute(sql_update)
psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction: ОШИБКА:  текущая транзакция прервана, команды до конца блока транзакции игнорируются

```
def table_update():
    conn = psycopg2.connect( dbname user host password)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("insert into us(A,B,C,D,F,G) "
                    "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", us_table)
    except: 
        print("Error")
        try:
            update = "UPDATE us set(A,B,C,D,F,G) = "
            where = " WHERE A = "
            sql_update = update + str(tuple(us_table)) + where + 
                "'" + us_table[0] + "'"
            cur.execute(sql_update)
        except KeyError as e2:
            print("Error", e2)
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: вы же уже работаете с `except`. Ну и обработайте ошибку так же.

Comment: Сергей,  просьба описать поподробнее как пропустить ошибку.

Comment: давайте наоборот, а то долго будет - вы `except KeyError as e1:` по какому принципу делали?

Comment: в моем понимании except должен обработать ошибку и отпустить дальше обрабатывать скрипт. но он в этой конфигурации except  репорт выдал и скрипт остановил. гдето в синтаксисе ошибка чтоли?

Comment: Тогда вопрос: у вас именно такая ошибка? (не указано в вопросе). Именно `Key Error`? Вывод ошибки тогда в вопрос включите, чтобы могли помочь.

Comment: поправил скрипт и добавил текст ошибки

Comment: То есть, теперь по-другому работает, так как до этого вообще ошибка не обрабатывалась. Я к этому и вёл. Советую теперь упросить пример до воспроизводимого минимума, чтобы убрать зависимости. Заодно в 50% случаев при этом приходит понимание, в чем ошибка.

Comment: если сократить код до первого except, то ошибка там следующая: psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: ОШИБКА:  повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "exist_pkey". Про эту ошибку я в курсе, именно из за нее я второй try поставил, если вообще имеет смысл так делать....

Comment: Так ваш `print("Error")` скрипт печатает? И в какой конкретно строке ошибка выходит которую питон показывает? Я подозреваю, что ошибка у вас на втором `cur.execute` валится или на `conn.commit()`. Почитайте про обработку ошибок в `postgresql`, может там при ошибке нужно `conn.rollback` делать? А то получается у вас ошибка вышла, а вы продолжаете какие-то SQL команды отдавать и потом ещё `commit` делаете. А как он сработает, если была ошибка в транзакции?

Comment: все верно он валится на втором cur.execute, но если поменять блоки местами и первым запустить именно его, то он отрабатывает без ошибок, дело не в cur.execute а в синтаксисе 2го try

Comment: Ох. Ещё раз. Проблема в том, что **первый** `cur.execute` **выполнился с ошибкой**. После этого **нельзя выполнять никакие команды в той же транзакции**. Нужно закрыть транзакцию и открыть новую. И только после этого делать следующий `cur.execute`. Я точно не знаю, как тут сработает, может можно сделать роллбэк и открыть новый курсор. А может нужно вообще закрывать коннекшен и открывать новый. Но делать всё-равно что-то надо именно с транзакциями, курсорами и коннекшенами, `try`-`except` за вас это не сделает!

Comment: оказывается в каждом try нужны свои open/close конекшн. Спасибо большое за идею,  выручили!!!

Answer (score 0):

В каждом try нужны свои open/close конекшн. Print после первого except:тоже ставить нельзя он не позволят второй функции запуститься. Правильно будет так:

```
def table_update():
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect( dbname user host password)
        cur = conn.cursor()        
        cur.execute("insert into us(A,B,C,D,F,G) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", us_table)
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
        print("insert ok")
    except: 
        try:
            update = "UPDATE us set(A,B,C,D,F,G) = "
            where = " WHERE A = "
            sql_update = update + str(tuple(us_table)) + where + 
                "'" + us_table[0] + "'"
            cur.execute(sql_update)
            conn.commit()
            cur.close()
            conn.close()
            print("update ok")
        except KeyError as e:
            print("Error", e)
```